# Conditionally formatting based on five criteria

Tags: if-statement, nested, conditional-statements

Each of three columns have text unique to each column. I want to compare each value from Column A to values in Column B and Column C.  If value is found in each of the three columns, change the background format to green. If only in Columns A & B, change background to orange. If only in columns B & C, change background to blue. If only in columns A & C, change background to yellow. If values are unique to their columns, change background to red.

I have tried multiple versions of conditional formatting for unique or matching values, but they only highlighted unique and duplicates for the entire range (all three columns), but they didn't work once I tried to customize them.

Duplicate values (Format Light Green Background with Dark Green text)=$E$1:$G$17  then Unique values (Format Light Red Background with Dark Red text)=$E$1:$G$17

The unique values are showing up ok, but the duplicate values are green no matter which of the three columns they are found in.  Not if all three green.

Comment: Please add some code and specify what language you are working with.

Comment: Excel.  I'm trying to automate the comparison of three lists.